# Different operations if operator is pressed with "Ctrl", "Alt" or "Shift" within the UI?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, shortcut, operator

I saw multiple add-ons that are using alternative operator action when pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> within the operator interface (I think it's only one of the 3).

I created an operator and draw it in in `properties>Object` and it'd like to batch use this operator with my selection while pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> as it is a default blender behavior when changing properties.

I was hoping that this feature could do the trick? maybe?
Are any templates available?